# Mostrar Cuadro de Diálogo para seleccionar una imagen en Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2015

Tengo el siguiente código para buscar una imagen en mi PC desde un formulario de Visual Basic y luego guardarla en una Base de Datos, pero presento un solo error al momento de abrir el cuadro de dialogo que busca la imagen. El código es el siguiente:

```
Private Sub AbrirImagen()
    Dim filename As String
    Dim openfiler As New OpenFileDialog
    With openfiler
        .InitialDirectory = "C:\"
        .Filter = "Archivos de imágen(*.jpg)|*.jpg|All Files (*.*)|*.*"
        .FilterIndex = 1
        .RestoreDirectory = True
    End With

    If openfiler.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then  
        filename = openfiler.FileName
        Me.PictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(filename)
    End If
End Sub
```

En la parte que dice `Windows.Forms` me sale el siguiente error:

> 'Forms' no es un miembro de 'Windows'

Me podrían ayudar? Trabajo en Visual Studio 2015

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si revisas la documentacion

[Form.DialogResult (Propiedad)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.windows.forms.form.dialogresult(v=vs.110).aspx)

veras que deberias definir el

```
Imports System.Windows.Forms
```

al principio del form, entonces en el codigo seria

```
If openfiler.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
```